# How to emulate an upload being in progress with p:fileUpload

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces 8 application which I need to style. One of the requirements is applying custom style to the UI that is shown when an upload is in progress in a `p:fileUpload` component using `auto="true"`. Triggering that UI by doing an actual upload will be very laborious. Is there a way to emulate the upload being in progress? I just want the UI elements to be visible in order to apply custom styling.

Comment: What I did previously is to upload a ridiculously large file and then in the HTML element inspector copy the "outer HTML" and then wait for it to finish and then put it back in. It'll stay there permanently. I imagine there's a better approach than that :)

Comment: @BalusC Thanks! I also thought of that in combination with reducing the bandwidth in the browser developer tools. I was hoping for a Javascript call. Hope one of the PF devs will know if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Kukeltje's answer will work, there is simpler way. While styling, use `auto="false"` instead. This will give you a preview of the file to upload, including a progress bar at 0%. Now, use the development tools to select the progress bar element with class name `ui-progressbar-value` and set the style properties to `display: block;` and any width. You can achieve this by simply and only using the DOM inspector.

[image]

See also:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Answer (score 5):

In The [Auto, Advanced (and non explicit single or multiple) showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/auto.xhtml) the follwing

```
var f = new File([""], "filename", { type: 'text/html' });
var data = new Object();
PF('widget_j_idt726_j_idt727').addFileToRow(f, data);
```

shows 'something'

[image: image after calling addFileToRow]

I got the `addFileToRow` from the [PrimeFaces fileupload javascript source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/c966236d7d28ded5273b2e2c436e2bfb5e98aaaa/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/fileupload/2-fileupload.js#L355)

You do get the following error

```
    TypeError: this.files[i].ajaxRequest.submit is not a function
```

But I think it can be ignored...

When you next call [ucfg.progress(...)](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/c966236d7d28ded5273b2e2c436e2bfb5e98aaaa/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/fileupload/2-fileupload.js#L310) on the widget and before this set some `data` properties/fields/...

```
data.files = [];
data.files[0] = f;
data.total = 100;
data.loaded = 10;

PF('widget_j_idt726_j_idt727').ucfg.progress(null, data);
```

It shows

[image]